# How can I redirect sound to a FIFO file?

Tags: audio, redirection, fifo

I have a program which uses FIFO files for interacting with the user. An audio call can be made directing the output of `arecord` to one of the program's FIFO files:

```
arecord -r 48000 -c 1 -f S16_LE > call_in
```

An audio call can be answered by directing the output of one of the program's FIFO files to `aplay`:

```
aplay -r 48000 -c 1 -f S16_LE - < call_out
```

How could an audio file be used in place of the first command, the one used to make a call? Let's say I want to play "sound.wav" into that `call_in` file, how could it be done?

Comment: Note that the WAV format contains a header with the total size of the file, so this format is not suitable for streaming or piping (unless both sides agree to ignore it, which `arecord` doesn't - it will attempt to fill the header on closing, and the seek will fail). So use `-t raw` (then you must specify parameters) or `-t au` (Sun sound format).

Comment: @dirkt Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I tried using a command like `aplay -c 1 -f S16_LE -t au sound.wav > call_in`, but what ended working was `ffmpeg -i sound.wav -ar 48000 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le pipe:1 > call_in`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Um, `sound.wav` is obviously a wav file, and not `au` format, so that can't work ... you'll have to *both* record and play in the same format. Using `ffmpeg` this way is the same as using raw format. But if it works, it works ...

Answer (score 1):

If `arecord`'s input is your sound card, then I suggest: `aplay sound.wav & arecord call_in`

`aplay` should play your message. The `&` allows the next command, `arecord`, to immediately execute, which should start recording what `aplay` is sending to your sound card.

Actually, `arecord call_in & aplay sound.wav` would probably be better, so you can be sure you're recording before the message plays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output of `arecord` is functionally like the contents of the wav file (i.e., they're the same media format), you could just do:

```
cat sound.wav > call_in
```